# Combine 2 rows into 1 with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

| title | email_sent | click_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 10 | 0.1 |
| abc | 2 | 0.2 |
| bcd | 3 | 0.4 |

I want to combine 2 records with the same title abc, email sent will be sum of 10 and 2, click_rate will be (0.1 * 10+0.2 * 2)/12

the desired df looks like:

| title | email_sent | click_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12 | 0.12 |
| bcd | 3 | 0.4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) here.

Just define a function that takes in a sub-dataframe (for each unique `title` that you have), and returns a Series with the calculated values. This Series will become the row. So the index values of this Series will become the column names of the new data frame:

```py
def f(df):
    n_emails = df['email_sent'].sum()
    click_rate = (df['click_rate'] * df['email_sent']).sum() / n_emails
    return pd.Series([n_emails, click_rate], 
                     index=['email_sent', 'click_rate'])

new_df = df.groupby('title').apply(f).reset_index()
```

**Example:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 10, 0.1], 
                   ['abc', 2,  0.2], 
                   ['bcd', 3,  0.4]], 
                  columns=['title', 'email_sent', 'click_rate'])
```

**Result:**

```py
  title  email_sent  click_rate
0   abc        12.0    0.116667
1   bcd         3.0    0.400000
```